# Select dataframe columns that starts with certain string and additional columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with columns: `'Id', 'Category', 'Shop', ....., 'Brandtxsu1', 'Brandxyw2', ...`

I want to select columns: `ID`, `Category`, and start with `Brand`. I can select the columns that start with `Brand` using the following code, but how do I select `ID` and `Category`?

```
df[df.columns[pd.Series(df.columns).str.startswith('Brand')]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `join` with `filter`

```py
out = df[['ID', 'Category']].join(df.filter(regex='^Brand'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a list of columns you want to filter for:

```
cols = [c for c in df.columns if c.startswith('Brand') or c in ('Id', 'Category', ...)]
df[cols]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

1. Select the 'Id' and 'Category' columns from the dataframe.
2. Select the columns from the dataframe whose column names start with 'Brand'.
3. `Join` them together.

**Sample Code**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Id':['001', '002', '003', '004'], 
    'Category':['A', 'A', 'S', 'B'],
    'Shop':['Shop1', 'Shop2', 'Shop3', 'Shop4'],
    'Brandtxsu1':[1, 1, 1, 1],
    'Brandxyw2':[2, 2, 2, 2]
})

df_output = df[['Id', 'Category']].join(df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith('Brand')])

print(df_output)
```

**Output**

```
    Id Category  Brandtxsu1  Brandxyw2
0  001        A           1          2
1  002        A           1          2
2  003        S           1          2
3  004        B           1          2
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is with [pd.filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```py
df.filter(regex="Id|Category|Brand.+")
Out[23]: 
    Id Category  Brandtxsu1  Brandxyw2
0  001        A           1          2
1  002        A           1          2
2  003        S           1          2
3  004        B           1          2
```

Another option is with [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) [select_columns](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.select.select_columns):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
df.select_columns('Id', 'Category', 'Brand*')
    Id Category  Brandtxsu1  Brandxyw2
0  001        A           1          2
1  002        A           1          2
2  003        S           1          2
3  004        B           1          2
```